# Acquiring iOS application name on the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

I just want to acquire an application name in the same way as a website domain. Is it possible to acquire a name without uploading the application to the App Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to reserve an app name you need to set up your app with your app name in App Store Connect. In order to do that you have to be enrolled for Apple's Developer Program which in other words means you have to pay the $99 per year cost. This way you will be able to register your app name, create beta versions and publish them with testers before you submit to app store.

Link to [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/)

To set up your application follow this [link](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev2cd126805)

Comment: i have paid  Apple's Developer Program can we have just register application, and will it  reserve for me

Comment: Ok already did this part, but not uploaded my app yet because its in initial development mode. is it enough to acquire app name by just register your application name on App Store Connect?

Comment: Can you see it under My Apps in App Store Connect?

Comment: Yes i can see it

Comment: So you are done. You now should be the owner of that app name for the next one year regardless of what the state of your app is.